# pulseaudio uses a dummy source when sarting a python script from init.d RPI4

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pulse-audio, a2dp

I'm using pulse audio to create a Bluetooth A2DP sink, which works fine until I try to launch a python program from boot.

I put this program into the init.d directory:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/startFlask
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          main.py
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting flask"
    # run application you want to start
    sudo python3 /home/pi/flask/main.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping flask"
    # kill application you want to stop
    killall python
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/startFlask{start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

which successfully launches my flask server but breaks PulseAudio.

upon running `pact list sinks short`, I get `auto_null`

and when running `pactl list sources short`, i get `auto_null.moitor`

could it be that running my python script stops pulseaudio from initializing, if so how do i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error to be that in the python script i was starting I was trying to play audio before the pulseaudio system/daemon had been started. I ended up "fixing" the problem by adding `time.sleep(5)` at the beginning of my program.

However, this is a temporary fix. In reality i would like to either start the python script after pulseaudio (have my program be the last thing to boot), or check in the python script and wait until the program is completely started.